# Plotly <-> Streamlit interactive buttons

Tags: plotly, mouseclick-event, streamlit

How do I make interactive buttons in plotly, that will change the chart and send their interaction to streamlit?

I have tried using the built in buttons in plotly https://plotly.com/python/custom-buttons/#relayout-button

This works for changing the chart, but the behavior cannot be sent out as an interaction of the click events here https://plotly.com/python/click-events/

There is currently only one library in streamlit to get the interactions of plotly charts and as far as I have seen, under the hood it uses the plotly events
https://github.com/null-jones/streamlit-plotly-events

So the only solution that I can come up with is to create a second chart as a subplot and style it to look like a button. This is a major hack and lots of red flags are popping up, but I cannot figure out another way to do it.

This is what I have so far:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, column_widths=[0.1, 0.7])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(x=[1, 1], y=['foo', 'bar'], orientation='h', width=.4, hoverinfo='skip'),
              row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(x=[1, 1], y=['foo', 'bar'], orientation='h', width=.4, hoverinfo='skip'),
              row=1, col=1)



fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=[1, 2],
        y=['foo', 'bar'],
        orientation='h',
        name='revenue',
        width=.4
    ),
    row=1, col=2)


fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=[2, 4],
        y=['foo', 'bar'],
        orientation='h',
        name='potential',
        width=.4
        
    ),
    row=1, col=2)
fig.update_yaxes(matches='y')

fig.update_layout(barmode='stack',
                  title_text="Multiple Subplots with Shared Y-Axes")


fig.show()
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem: I needed to display a specific video according to the click action on a scatter plot. My first attempt was similar to your code above, but then I found this link, https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/how-to-show-audio-player-when-point-on-interactive-plot-is-clicked/20664, in the Streamlit forum, where I got the null-jones addon for Plotly, https://github.com/null-jones/streamlit-plotly-events. This specific addon returns a list of dicts with the following format:

```py
{
    x: int (x value of point),
    y: int (y value of point),
    curveNumber: (index of curve),
    pointNumber: (index of selected point),
    pointIndex: (index of selected point)
}
```

If you could use the coordinates or index information to set up your update logic, then this probably can help you out. For instance, my approach was as follows:

1. I've installed the addon using pip: `pip install streamlit-plotly-events`;
2. I've generated the scatter plot figure using the `hover_name` property set with the video paths:

   ```py
   import plotly.express as px
   fig = px.scatter(df, x=0, y=1, hover_name=df.paths)
   ```
3. I've created a dict for mapping the hover_text and the scatter plot's coordinates:

   ```py
   x_data = fig.data[0]['x']
   y_data = fig.data[0]['y']
   hoverdata = fig.data[0]['hovertext']
   for x_val, y_val, text in zip(x_data, y_data, hoverdata):
       if (x_val, y_val) not in st.session_state.data_dict.keys():
           st.session_state.data_dict[(x_val, y_val)] = text
   ```
4. Using the addon, I got the coordinates of each clicked point:

   ```py
   from streamlit_plotly_events import plotly_events

   # this line displays the plot already
   selected_points = plotly_events(fig, click_event=True)

   current_x = selected_points[0]['x']
   current_y = selected_points[0]['y']
   video_path = st.session_state.data_dict[(current_x, current_y)]
   ```
5. With the video_path, the last step was to display the video in the app using the `st.video()` method:

   ```py
   video_file = open(video_path, 'rb')
   video_bytes = video_file.read()
   st.video(video_bytes)
   ```

Comment: I've listed the null-jones library above as well. What I don't seem to get from you example is how I can create **buttons** (and not use the chart traces)

Comment: (I need the buttons to be aligned with the y-axis, which is always different of different length. I could put the buttons outisde of the chart, but I cannot align them with the chart that way.)

Comment: To could use the null-jones addon and get a button that behaves like the ones in here, https://plotly.com/python/custom-buttons/#relayout-button, the most naive solution I could think about right now is to modify the custom component typescript file to get the button info. This pull request here does a similar modification: https://github.com/null-jones/streamlit-plotly-events/pull/3. By adding a button in the chart with `update_layout`, you would like to return the `data['layout']['update_menus']`, where `data` is the plot json file.